# Use a button to pass data to a database

Tags: php, html, sql

I don't know if this is valid question for this site, but...

I'm wondering how can I use buttons to add data to a database without the use of forms? I have a Table of "Products" and I want to click a button beside each product information to add that Item to an orderList in my Database. (User Cart for purchases)

So assign a value to the button so when it's clicked it will match the unique product_id in the databse and will know what product is being selected. Thus if I click each button it will mimick a user adding a product to their cart.

I have nine products in my database (don't mind the extra 1)... So I want to click a button so it will generate an action that will populate another table within my DB.

Thanks

```
    <pre>
<b>ID   Description         Stock Left  Price   Order ID</b>
</pre>
    <table align="left" border="1px" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="18" style="width: 450px;">


<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "inserter";
$password = "123456";
$dbname = "pc_master_race";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT product_id, product_name, current_stock, product_price FROM stock";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

     echo "<tr><td>". $row["product_id"] . "</td><td>". $row["product_name"] . "</td><td>". $row["current_stock"] . "</td><td>". $row["product_price"] . "</td></tr>";
     }
} else 
{
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
</table>

<br> <input value="Order 1" type="submit"><br>
<br> <input value="Order 1" type="submit"><br>
<br> <input value="Order 2" type="submit"><br>
<br> <input value="Order 3" type="submit"><br>
<br> <input value="Order 4" type="submit"><br>
<br> <input value="Order 5" type="submit"><br>
<br> <input value="Order 6" type="submit"><br>
<br> <input value="Order 7" type="submit"><br>
<br> <input value="Order 8" type="submit"><br>
<br> <input value="Order 9" type="submit"><br>
```

[image: Browse Page]

Comment: If you're not posting a code example, it's likely not a valid question. What you got so far?

Comment: Are you looking to use AJAX?

Comment: Why did you post a select statement and html displaying the results when you are tying to grab data and do an insert statement :[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap each of your items such that they are their own form. This way you can post the data for a specific order.

```
<table align="left" border="1px" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="18" style="width: 450px;">
<thead>
  <tr><th>ID</th><th>Description</th><th>Stock Left</th></th>Price</th><th>Order ID</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "inserter";
$password = "123456";
$dbname = "pc_master_race";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT product_id, product_name, current_stock, product_price FROM stock";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>{$row['product_id']}</td><td>{$row['product_name']}</td><td>{$row['current_stock']}</td><td>{$row['product_price']}</td><td><form action="placeorder.php" method="post"><input type='hidden' name='order_id' value='{$row['product_id']}'><button type='submit'>Order {$row['product_id']}</button></form></td></tr>";
     }
} else {
   echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```